# C : Clearing/Overwritting specific space in Array

Tags: c, arrays, string, sudoku

I have two char Arrays
- char grid [9] [9]
- char possible_values [9] [9] [10]

the grid array is a 9x9 Sudoku where the empty spaces are filled with '0'. 
The possible_values array is a 9x9 Array where in every spaces is filled with  the numbers which are possible for the sudoku "123456789".

Now I want to loop over the grid array & in every space where there is already a certain number (123456789) I want to clear the possible_value array spaces for the specific space.

```
    int j, k;
    char empty_string [] = "";
    char possible_values[9][9][10];
    char grid [9][9];

    for(j=0; j<9; j++){
        for(k=0; k<9; k++){

                printf("%d %d = %c -> pv = %s", j, k, grid[j][k], possible_values[j][k]);

                if (grid[j][k] < 0 ){
                    memcpy(possible_values[j][k], empty_string, 10);

                }

                printf("%d %d = %c -> pv = %s", j, k, grid[j][k], possible_values[j][k]);                   

        }
    }
```

I already filled the two arrays in two outsorced methods.

Now if I run the programm the value of possible_values stays the same and doesn't get overwritten with the empty string.

I already tried setting the array-space NULL

Can somebody help me ? And I think that overwritting the possible_value string is a rather strange way to "clear" the string but I didn't find a method to completly clear the specific space of the array ?

EDIT :

Here is the whole code

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*****************************************************************************************************/
void sudoku_read(char sudoku[9][9]){
 
 int j, k;
    char filename[100];

    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE *file1 = fopen(filename, "r");

    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        for(k=0;k<9;k++){
         fscanf(file1,"%c\t", &sudoku[j][k]);
        }
    }    
 
 fclose(file1);
}
/*****************************************************************************************************/
void set_possible_values(char possible_values[9][9][10]){
 
 int j, k;
    char string [] = "123456789";

    
 for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        for(k=0;k<9;k++)
        {
            memcpy(possible_values[j][k], string, 10);
        }
    } 
}
/*****************************************************************************************************/
void sudoku_solve(char grid[9][9]) {
     
     int j, k, i;
     char empty_string [] = "";
  char possible_values[9][9][10];

  set_possible_values(possible_values);

  for(j=0; j<9; j++){
   for(k=0; k<9; k++){

     printf("%d %d = %c -> pv = %s", j, k, grid[j][k], possible_values[j][k]);
     warten();

     if (grid[j][k] < 0 ){
      memset(possible_values[j][k], 0, 10);
      
     }

     printf("%d %d = %c -> pv = %s", j, k, grid[j][k], possible_values[j][k]); 
     warten ();    

   }
  } 
    
 
  for(j=0; j<9; j++){
   for(k=0; k<9; k++){
    if(grid[j][j] != 0){
    printf("grid[%d][%d] = %c", j, k, grid[j][k]);
    printf("\tThe possible values of cell [%d][%d] are [%s]\n", j, k, possible_values[j][k]);
    }
   }
  } 

}
/*****************************************************************************************************/
int main(void) {
    
 int n;
 int i;
 int j;
 int k;
 
 char board[9][9];
 
 printf("How many Sudokus shoul be solved: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
   
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  sudoku_read(board);
        sudoku_solve(board);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `empty_string` is your problem.

Comment: I think you want to use `memset` instead of `memcpy`: [memset documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)

Comment: Oh... Plenty of other wrong stuff there!!! The `grid` array is not initialized, so it contains "junk" data. What exactly are you hoping to achieve by printing it (let alone, by checking it in the `if` statement)??? In addition, it is a `char` array, and you are printing its values as integers (`%d`). Are you sure that this is indeed your intention?

Comment: I initially posted this as an answer, but your code contains several other errors (as I mentioned in the comment above), so I deleted it. Here is the most critical error... The size of the `empty_string` array is a single character (which is set to 0). So `memcpy(possible_values[j][k], empty_string, 10)` yields undefined behavior. If you want to fill `possible_values[j][k]` with 10 zeros, then you can simply call `memset(possible_values[j][k], 0, 10)`. But if you just want to set it to an empty null-terminated string, then you might as well call `possible_values[j][k][0] = 0`.

Comment: String operations such as `strcpy`, `strcat`, `strlen` and `printf` with `"%s"` will not refer to any other value beyond that first character (which is now set to 0), so `possible_values[j][k]` will essentially become an empty string.

Comment: I think `sudoku_solve`  isn't a good name to describe the function

Answer (score 0):

Your empty string is only 1 large (a 0x00 value, to signify the end of a string). You will copy a bunch of garbage from after that value into the place you want to clear. A better option is to use `memset(possible_values[j][k], 0, 10);`.

Comment: Ok it works with the memset-method i can overwrite things. But in my programm it doesn't overwritte anything still the same as before - something wrong with my If-method ?

Comment: Have you initialized your grid-array to anything? Otherwise it will be filled with garbage. It currently checks if it's below zero, which you don't ensure anywhere.

Comment: Yeah all grids are initialized.

Comment: You should add all the relevant code to your example

Comment: Variable `grid` is probably meant to be an `int` array, not a `char` array (judging by the way it is "treated" in the `printf` call and in the `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Two sugegstions:
1. Have your character buffer null termintated always
2. Do strncpy instead of memcpy upto 9 chars and leave 10th char for null as below:

```
strncpy(possible_values[j][k], string, 10-1);
possible_values[j][k][10-1]='\0';
```

And also, in other places where similar things are used